# How to code for onMouseOver event in Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, jquery, autodesk-forge

I have created a simple extension in autodesk forge. 
The idea is that when I make a mouse-over event on a 3D object it has to show me the ID of the hovered object/sub-object my extension code runs like this.

```js
AutodeskNamespace("Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension");


Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent = function (viewer, options) {

    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);

    var _self = this;
    var _viewer = viewer;
    var _selectedId = null;

//On Load of the exension function
    _self.load = function () {

 _viewer.addEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.MOUSE_OVER_EVENT,
            _self.onMouseOver);

          console.log("Autodesk.ADN.MouseEvent loaded");
         return true;
 };

 //On unload of the exension function
      _self.unload = function () {
 
 _viewer.removeEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.MOUSE_OVER_EVENT,
            _self.onMouseOver);

        console.log("Autodesk.ADN.MouseEvent unloaded");
        return true;
    };

// Event function initialization
_self.onMouseOver = function (event) {

        var dbId = event.dbIdArray[0];

        if (typeof dbId !== 'undefined') {

            _selectedId = dbId;
            alert('ID: ' + _selectedId);
        }
        else _selectedId = null;
    }
};
Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent.prototype =
    Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent.prototype.constructor =
    Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent;

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
    'Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent',
    Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent);
```

but the onMouseOver function is not working, can anyone please help me? thanks in advance.

PS: I have included the extensions in the script tags and the extension is loaded likewise.

```
oViewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MouseEvent');
```

I also get a confirmation from the console that the extension is loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event as `Autodesk.Viewing.MOUSE_OVER_EVENT` ... did you just made that up or you got it from some - apparently incorrect - source?

The way to handle that would be to use a viewer tool (see that post for [details](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html)), then in `handleMouseMove` callback, do the following:

```
handleMouseMove (event) {

  var hitTest = _self.viewer.clientToWorld(
    event.canvasX,
    event.canvasY,
    true)

  if (hitTest) {

    console.log(hitTest)
  }
}
```

Here is another post I wrote about [viewer events](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/10/event-watcher-extension-for-view-data.html), it is a bit old, so there are a couple more now but can give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thank You @Philippe Leefsma =)

Comment: Between I just made that up I thought the mouse events are common in autodesk forge and implemented that. @Philippe Leefsma

Comment: The viewer API is specific to the viewer. Depending on what you are doing, you may rely on lower level Three.js API calls, but making up event names in a non-strictly typed language like js will not get you very far...